# React State variable keeps resetting and changing within one render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```js
export default function Questionnaire(props) {
    const initialState = {
        questionCount: 0,
        is_host: false
    }
    const [ roomData, setRoomData ] = useState(initialState) 
    const { roomCode } = useParams()
    const [ displayedTable, setDisplayedTable ] = useState(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/audio/get-room" + "?code=" + roomCode)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            setRoomData({
              roomData,
              questionCount: data.questionCount,
              is_host: data.is_host,
            })
          })

          window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            console.log("questionCount 1:", roomData.questionCount);
            if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                setDisplayedTable(showNextStage(displayedTable, roomData.questionCount));
            } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                setDisplayedTable(showPreviousStage(displayedTable));
            }
        });

        // cleanup this component
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.keyCode == '39') {
                setDisplayedTable(showNextStage(displayedTable, roomData.questionCount));
            } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
                setDisplayedTable(showPreviousStage(displayedTable));
            }
        });
        };
    },[roomCode,setRoomData])

    console.log("questionCount 2:", roomData.questionCount);

    return (
        <div>
            {components[displayedTable]}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Every time the State refreshes, the two console.logs() return "questionCount 1: 0" and "questionCount 2: 5" (the value fetch() retrieves). But since questionCount is only set to 0 in the initial UseState(), it shouldn't be resetting to 0 and should remain at 5 after it gets set to that. But it doesn't. Why is this? How is it even possible for the one State variable to have two different values in the one render(), when State changes are meant to rerender the page?

Comment: because you not pass roomData to dependencies array of useEffect, so the console log questionCount 1 always be 0

Comment: Weird. The useEffect hook is meant to rerun after setRoomData is used in any case, which updates roomData.questionCount. So why doesn't it rerun with the updated variable?

Comment: Ok it runs the EventListener twice every time I press an arrow key for some reason, and gives 0 the first time and 5 the second.